# Remote shell using python

Tags: python, linux, shell, sockets, remote-access

I want to do a simple remote shell. I have used sockets to comunicate and it works, in LAN. Now my friend is trying to connect to my server script from his client but he cannot do it.
I have opened port 4333 public and associated it to 10001 private in my router.

By the way I've replaced the IP with XX.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Client's script


import socket
import sys
import os

# I create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server_address = ('XX.XXX.XX.XX', 4333)
sock.connect(server_address)


datos = sock.recv(30)

comando = str(datos)
os.system(comando)
```

=========

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Server's script


import socket
import sys

# I create the TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

direc = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
# Socket link
server_address = (direc, 10001)
connection = sock.bind(server_address)

sock.listen(1)

coman = ''
while coman != 'salir':
    # Awaiting conecction
    print "Esperando conexion..."
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()
    coman = raw_input("Introduce comando: ")
    connection.sendall(coman)


connection.close()
```

Comment: Server is listening on port 10001, but client is attempting to connect to port 4333. No way that can work even if IP addresses were correct.

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of `direc`? It should be a connectable IP address for your server to work, i.e. `127.0.0.1` doesn't work for your friends, even they are under same LAN with your machine.

`sock.bind()` means that the socket will only listen connections to `direc`:`10001`. You can use `0.0.0.0` to represent "the whole internet".